# Did Ramsay Macdonald have a Vietnamese mistress living near Downing Street?

Tags: united-kingdom, great-britain

[An article from the Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/aug/01/why-carrie-symonds-is-the-embodiment-of-the-boris-johnson-brand)
contains this intriguing sentence:

> Ramsay MacDonald allegedly had a long relationship with a Vietnamese woman in a house a short walk from Westminster.

However, I cannot find any other corroboration or debunking about this allegation: is it an actual rumour, and if so what evidence, if any, exists for it?

Comment: https://www.express.co.uk/news/history/1628703/The-Prime-Ministers-Affair-Book-Andrew-Williams

Comment: So, **"Viennese"**, not "Vietnamese". That's probably why you were having trouble finding it. Those extra 3 letters kind of make a big difference.

Comment: @T.E.D. - you haven't lived till you've had a Hanoi schnitzel.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Ramsay MacDonald had several affairs, one of which was with a **Viennese** socialite - Frau Kristina Forster.

This is according to a book review of "Former Panorama producer Andrew Williams's juicy  historical novel"  [The Prime Minister's Affair](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/books/what-to-read/oswald-mosley-ramsay-macdonald-pornographic-blackmail-letters/) entitled *Oswald Mosley, Ramsay MacDonald and the pornographic blackmail letters* (link behind a paywall)

> In 1929 Ramsay MacDonald, embarking on his second term as prime minister, was threatened with blackmail by an ex-lover. A Viennese socialite called Frau Forster, newly ruined in the Crash, threatened to publish his “pornographic” letters to her if he didn’t stump up some hush money. That, anyway, was the story as related in old age by Sir Oswald Mosley, who claimed to have dealt with the problem at MacDonald’s behest by sending “the old girl” packing with threats of imprisonment (Mosley was then a Labour MP, and one of MacDonald’s ministers)...

[The PM, his spurned lover and a cache of risqué letters](https://www.express.co.uk/news/history/1628703/The-Prime-Ministers-Affair-Book-Andrew-Williams) mentions that:

> The Prime Minister’s ex-lover was renting a flat in Horseferry Road – a poor district of London at the time – but only a few streets from Mosley’s grand house in Smith Square.

More about "[Sex, blackmail, and Downing street](https://www.andrewwilliams.tv/books/the-prime-ministers-affair/sex-blackmail-and-downing-stree/)" from Andrew William's site.

Comment: Makes a change from the Austria/Australia confusion I sometimes see.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Still the same country causing all the trouble. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. - my teenage son told me one of his classmates in a modern history lesson thought Hitler was born in Australia, and furthermore did not think it odd.